# Add custom data to breeze metadata on server

Tags: breeze

In a app I'm developing I create some UI widgets that are generated based on breeze metadata and attributes on my classes and properties. So on the server I read the attributes, and add them on breeze's generated metadata. On the client, after I load the metadata I add those attributes on the type.
An example of this
(on the client, after the *enriched* metadata loads):

```
function finishMetadata(md) {

    for (var i = 0; i < md.schema.entityType.length; i++) {
        var et = md.schema.entityType[i];
        var etype = manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(et.name);

        //isExportable is a class attribute
        etype.isExportable = et.isExportable;

        for (var j = 0; j < et.property.length; j++) {
            var p = et.property[j];
            var prop = etype.getProperty(p.name);
            //displayName is a property attribute
            prop.displayName = p.displayName ? p.displayName : p.name;
        }
    }
}
```

with this, when I call `manager.metadataStore.getEntityType(entityName)`, I get all the entityType data, including the properties and all the attributes I added on the server.

This worked fine until today. I have added inheritance (TPT) on some classes (Customer:Person) and since the generated metadata from the  Customer entity does not have the Person properties, I cannot add them to the metadataStore type. When I call `metadataStore.getEntityType` for `Person`, I get all attributes, but when I call it for `Customer` I do not get my custom attributes (and this is because on the code above `Customer` does not list the parent `Person` properties so I do not have the chance to plug in my custom attributes.

Anyway, this feels hacky and messy, even to explain it. So here we are, breeze its in version 1.4.7 and I wonder if there is an easier way of adding custom data to the metadata that would not break with TPT?

PS.: I know that I can hand-craft the metadata but I would like to stick with the default as much as possible to avoid problems with future changes. So, basically all metadata changes should be minimal and automatic, based on the classes.

Answer (score 1):

Well, I ended up goind further down on the way I'm doing things. Instead of just use `manager.metadataStore.getEntityType` to get the type data (which does not bring my custom metadata), I look if my entityType has a baseType and if it does, I load that base type data and merge it with the child class. In my case, basically I get the dataProperties of the `Person` and use them instead of the dataProperties of the `Customer`. It works but I still looking for a cleaner and simpler way of doing something like this.